# How to add left and right edge effect when ViewPager2's user input is disabled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview, android-viewpager2

Since my app lags during left/right transitions between fragments in a `ViewPager2`, I decided to disable its native swipe function with `viewPager2!!.isUserInputEnabled=false`. However, this also disabled the blue colored edge effect when swiping horizontally for fragments at either ends.

As my fragments also use vertical `ScrollView`, I noticed that the top and bottom edge effects work. Therefore, could it be possible to add left and right edge effects to a custom/extended vertical `ScrollView`? I believe left and right edge effects already are in place for horizontal `ScrollView`.

I also found the documentation regarding [EdgeEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect) where `android.widget.EdgeEffect` also can be extended:

```
class Edge(context: Context) : EdgeEffect(context) {
    // override functions
}
```

However, I don't know how I can apply it in order to add left/right edge effect to a vertical ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a Viewpager if you don't want the fragments to be swipeable. Replace your ViewPager element with a Framelayout and add your fragment to this framelayout programatically.

Comment: Hello, actually, I wanted to have swipe but without the transition animation. As far as I know, the animation cannot be made instant with ViewPager2 since it's final, so I just disabled its swipe and added a custom implementation for it. I also have a TabLayout that I still use for the fragments.